# Programming design efficiency

Tags: java, performance

I'm currently writing a piece of code that handles the User Interface of my app.
The code has the objective of setting the location of text in orientation to two other points (centering the text). For example:

```
PointX 1 = 50;
PointX 2 = 150;
```

This input would yield the X value of the text to be `100`.

My question now is that each time when the UI is refreshed this simple calculation is performed. Is this permissible or should I create a variable that stores the x value?

NB: The reason why I'm not going with the variable method, is that this would up the amount of variables in my code, which I'm not a big fan of, since I'm trying to keep my code as clean, simply and maintainable as possible.

Comment: Try both and benchmark the difference. Or try one and use a profiler to see how many times the calculation is performed.

Comment: JVM will cache the value probably. Would make no difference. Such micro-optimizations aren't necessary

Comment: Calculations > Variables, especially when calculations are simple.

Comment: My advice would be to always choose the simplest and most obvious solution first. And if it isn't performing as well as it should, only then start optimising.

Comment: Thanks guys. I guess that confirms that then. So this is a miniscule performance issue. I'll be sticking with the calculations then.

Comment: If values of PointX1 and PointX2 are not changing while UI is getting refreshed, your values will not be calculated again.

Comment: The middle of two values? that's like... nothing, even if it was calculated, it's fairly negligible, even at a low level. I wouldn't do it myself though, maybe it's a matter of taste, but an extra variable seems more readable and maintainable to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to keep it simple and keep memory down I would keep it the way you have it now. I'd assume that you are finding the average between the two values and this is not a very expensive operation.